# Replace edittext text

Tags: android, android-edittext

In My Android Studio project I designed a `editText` with button click.(kind of translation.)
When user input some text in `editText` and click the button the `editText` chracters replaced by other.

```
  EditText  small=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
                String str = small.getText().toString();
               str=str.replace("nys","La");
            str=str.replace("iy","Lai");
            str=str.replace("Ny","Li");
            str=str.replace("Nyh","Lo");
            str=str.replace("yh","Low");
            str=str.replace("Y}","L");
            str=str.replace("yP","LA");
            str=str.replace("y","Lu");
//Likewise has lot of vice versa replaces
 EditText capital=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
                capital.setText(str);
```

Is this correct ?

Can I place this replace function into another class and call here..? How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do it, create a static function in one of your class and call in your current class.

Defining common function

```
public static String replaceCharacters(String inputString) {
    inputString=inputString.replaceAll("nys","La");
    inputString=inputString.replaceAll("iy","Lai");
    inputString=inputString.replaceAll("Ny","Li");
    inputString=inputString.replaceAll("Nyh","Lo");
    inputString=inputString.replaceAll("yh","Low");
    inputString=inputString.replaceAll("Y}","L");
    inputString=inputString.replaceAll("yP","LA");
    inputString=inputString.replaceAll("y","Lu");
    return inputString;
}
```

Calling from your activity class

```
EditText small=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
EditText capital=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
capital.setText(""+YourClassName.replaceCharacters(small.getText().toString()));
```

Comment: didn't got it, what do you want?

Comment: When I click the button the characters are multiplied. Here I want to show you my function. How can I post here the full code ..  https://drive.google.com/open?id=16Zq-slfQqpAfpwwufgUG4Jq7wd3nnDJ4

Comment: if you want to replace all occurring of same character then you need to use `replaceAll()`

Comment: you need to write replaceAll only once to replace all matching characters from string. check updated answer.

Comment: Ok.. Thank You... But when I click button the app has closed.. Ok .. I am going to do this via local html.. Thank You Karan.